# Где ставить запятые?

Tags: синтаксис

Где нужно поставить запятые в предложении: Для их производства применяют такой материал как сталь содержащую углерод в количестве менее чем 0,25%.

Comment: Почитайте правила сайта. Хотя бы в части — какие вопросы не приветствуются.

Answer (score 4):

Нужны две запятые.
Первая перед союзом "как" (присутствует указательное слово "такой").
Вторая - перед причастным оборотом.

*Для их производства применяют такой материал, как сталь, содержащую углерод в количестве менее чем 0,25 %.*

[**ТАКОЙ (,) КАК, местоимение + союз**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722)

> По общему правилу, обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в
>   основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».
>
> Он,
>   рыжий человечек, может назвать такие имена, как Малянов Дмитрий
>   Алексеевич, астроном, Губарь Захар Захарович, инженер, и Снеговой
>   Арнольд Павлович, химико-физик. А. и Б. Стругацкие, За миллиард лет до
>   конца света. Быть может, только такие люди, как Шиллер, могли быть
>   достойны ее любви. К. Паустовский, Ручьи, где плещется форель. Отчего
>   же ты не старый, // А такой, как был тогда? А. Ахматова, Веет ветер
>   лебединый... «…Это в общем сон, но не такой, как обычно»... Б.
>   Окуджава, Путешествие дилетантов. Садись такой, как ты есть. Не
>   принаряжайся. Б. Пастернак, Доктор Живаго. Дуб был точно такой, как в
>   царскосельском саду. Ю. Тынянов. Кюхля. Такие, как ты, рождались во
>   все эпохи кровавой истории наших планет. А. и Б. Стругацкие, Трудно
>   быть богом. Теперь, хлопче, скажу тебе, и бабы не такие, как прежде.
>   В. Короленко, Лес шумит.
>
> Однако в некоторых случаях запятая ставится
>   не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой»:
>
> 1) если слова «такой
>   как» соотносятся с предшествующим прилагательным: Погода дождливая,
>   такая как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была мрачная, такая как в
>   старинных замках (ср.: Погода такая, как осенью. Обстановка в этом
>   доме была такая, как в старинных замках);
>
> 2) если слова «такие как»
>   употребляются после обобщающего слова перед рядом однородных членов
>   (после слов «такие как» двоеточие не требуется): Туристы посетили
>   старинные города, такие как Суздаль, Владимир, Ростов Великий.

Отмечу, что до сих пор [нет твёрдого правила](http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=833&0g1=595&0t1=743) о необходимости делать пробел перед знаком процента.

> Впервые издательских справочниках требование отбивать знак процента
>   появилось в 1998 году.
>
> Мильчин А. Э., Чельцова Л. К. Справочник издателя и автора.
>   Редакционно-издательское оформление издания. М.: Олимп, 1998. Страница
>   111, первый абзац сверху: "последняя цифра числа отбивается от
>   обозначения единицы на 2 п., в том числе и от обозначений °С и %...".
>
> Однако это правило до сих пор не является общепризнанным. Многие
>   издательства, следуя традиции, которой несколько десятков лет, по
>   прежнему пишут знак процента слитно с числом, хотя и нарушают при этом
>   требования ГОСТ 8.417-2002 (заменившего ГОСТ 8.417-81).